# Label and integer as input for neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, regression

I want to do regression using a neural network. As input I have a real value and I want the neural network to predict a real value as well. So far it works already. Now I also have a independent variable consisting of classes (the weekdays in this case) which I would like to use as second input to get a better prediction. Is it possible for a regression to have two different inputs, one real value and one class?

I know that I could just encode the weekdays to numbers 1-7 (which I guess I have to do anyway), but then the neural network would assume it to be real numbers, right? But there is no ranking between the weekdays, so how can I make sure they are treated as classes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are right that you can encode the weekdays to number `1-7`.

Then, look into using an `embedding layer` to convert this encoding to an embedding.

Then, pass the output of this `embedding layer` to your network where you see fit.

**A little more info**

The intuition behind the `embedding layer` is that your network will backprop through its input. In effect, the embedding for each day of the week will correspond to a real-valued vector and this embedding will be updated with each minibatch to minimize your loss functions.

update: Having such a learned embedding for the day of the week is a good idea since it will carry more information about the effect of each day of the week on your target than a simple integer or one-hot encoding. For example, if 2 distinct days have a similar effect on the target, your network will be able to project its embedding close to one another making this projection more meaningful than an integer or one-hot encoding.

**Functions of interest**

`tf.keras.layers.Embedding`

`torch.nn.Embedding`

**Tutorials**

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/embedding
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html

**Papers**

[word2vec paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf)

Comment: ok, so I worked through that and learned a lot (thanks again!). But so far I still didn't figure out, if and how it is possible to combine my weekdays input and my real value input. Can I just take the embedded weekdays and add them as second input to the real value input? It still doesn't feel right to me

Comment: There are many operations that you can perform on your embeddings; so there won't be a direct answer to your comment. In your position, you can look into `concatenate`-ing the learned embedding to your other features.

Comment: You didn't justify why using an embedding layer is more appropriate than simply one hot encoding the days of the week. Embeddings are usually helpful when the different possible values are related in ways that are hard to specify and thus must be learned.